# GDB empty backtrace when using gunicorn core dump

Tags: python, c, docker, gdb, gunicorn

I'm trying to make a core dump of gunicorn in one docker container and debug it in another one.
Gunicorn is running with python3.5.
When I'm opening core file in the container where it was dumped, everything looks fine:

```
Reading symbols from /opt/pyenv/versions/3.5.0/bin/python3.5...done.
[New LWP 786]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/opt/pyenv/versions/3.5.0/bin/python3.5'.
#0  0x00007f7caec93af3 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f7caec93af3 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x00007f7cacdaf213 in pyepoll_poll (self=0x7f7ca5aa9a80, args=<optimized out>, kwds=<optimized out>) at /tmp/python-build.20160412233915.330/Python-3.5.0/Modules/selectmodule.c:1549
#2  0x00000000005a7579 in PyCFunction_Call (func=func@entry=0x7f7c98706090, args=args@entry=0x7f7c9feb5550, kwds=kwds@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:98
...
```

But when I'm trying to open this file in the another container I have built for debugging purpose, I've got this:

```
Reading symbols from /opt/pyenv/versions/3.5.0/bin/python3.5...done.

warning: exec file is newer than core file.
[New LWP 356]

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/356' in core file.
Core was generated by `/opt/pyenv/versions/3.5.0/bin/python3.5'.

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/356' in core file.
#0  0x00007fb1e8695af3 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fb1e8695af3 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fb1e67b1213 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000225b588 in ?? ()
#3  0x0034e2b269edb810 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000000003ff in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000400000001 in ?? ()
```

I can't understand why I'm getting the empty backtrace. Maybe someone can help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: "warning: exec file is newer than core file." should make you suspicious already.

Comment: No, this is because core dump was built earlier than python.

Comment: Exactly. Just think what that can imply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the another container I have built for debugging purpose, I've got this:

It's not clear what you mean by "I have built for debugging".

In general, the binary you use to analyze the core dump *must* match the binary which produced this core dump *exactly*.

That means you can't do this:

```
gcc -O2 -o foo t.c
./foo  # crashes, produces core dump

gcc -g -o foo-g t.c  # note lack of -O2
gdb ./foo-g core     # will not work!
```

Instead, what you should do is this:

```
gcc -g -O2 -o foo-g t.c  # optimize with debug info
cp foo-g foo
strip -g foo   # make a production binary by removing debug info

./foo             # crashes, produces a core dump
gdb ./foo-g core  # this works!
```

To test whether the two binaries are sufficiently "same", you can compare their symbols, e.g.

```
diff <(readelf -Ws foo-g) <(readelf -Ws foo)
```

The debug binary *can* have symbols not present in the stripped binary (such as `LOCAL` functions), but symbols that are present in both binaries must have the same value.

I am guessing that your "built for debugging" `python3.5` is not the same as your "production" `python3.5`.

Comment: Even though I was building python in different containers the same way, they are really differs. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: I finally found the reason why python binaries was different. Original container was on ubuntu, but my debug container was on debian, so python was compiled in different environments.